# Multiline option in jQuery autocomplete dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I am using jQuery autocomplete in my asp.net application for selecting an item name. Now I want to display a short description below the item. Something like this:
[Item Description below Item name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nN7M.png)

My cs file C# code is:

```
public string[] itemAutocomplete(string prefix)
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        ds = autoCompleteItemNameF(prefix);     
List<string> autolist = new List<string>();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 )
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                autolist.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["good_name"].ToString()+ "-" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["description"].ToString());
            }
          }
        return autolist.ToArray();
```

My jquery function is:

```
function item_autocomplete() {

            $("[id$=txt_item_name]").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("../Services/AutoComplete.asmx/itemAutocomplete") %>',
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.split('-')[0]
                                     }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {

                    $("[id$=txt_item_name]").change();
                },
                minLength: 1
            });

        };
```

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Comment: Thank you Bhuban Shrestha. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Bhuban, I used the inbuilt functionality of jquery provided here:
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data